# How to fix divide by zero in asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net, sql, razor

I've got a group of query strings that run as follows:

```
var nq = db.QueryValue("select COALESCE(COUNT(*),0)from OPPORTUNITY where START_DATE = DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate())");  
var nrt = db.QueryValue("select COALESCE(COUNT(*),0)from OPPORTUNITY where START_DATE = DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()) and OPPORTUNITY_STAGE = '-1'");  
var nrep = nrt / nq;
```

All it gives me is unhandled exeption: cannot divide by zero.

There is often going to be a zero in either or both of the first two  query results. How do I get it to display NaN (not a number) instead of crashing?

I'm sure I've asked this before, but I couldn't seem to find what the answer was.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about adding `IF` condition?

```
var nq = db.QueryValue("select COALESCE(COUNT(*),0)from OPPORTUNITY where START_DATE = DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate())");

var nrep = 0;
if (nq != 0)
{
var nrt = db.QueryValue("select COALESCE(COUNT(*),0)from OPPORTUNITY where START_DATE = DATEDIFF(d,0,getdate()) and OPPORTUNITY_STAGE = '-1'");
nrep = nrt / nq;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace

```
var nrep = nrt / nq;
```

with

```
Double nrep = Double.NaN;
if (nq != 0)
{
    nrep = nrt / nq;
}
```

Comment: It says "expected { but found nrep"

Comment: Would have worked, I think. i've used @John Woo answer below.

Comment: Actually, I tried both, but I like john's version better. I did ask for NaN, but John's gives me 0.00 which is more 'user friendly' at the display end. But yes, your answer did work.

Comment: @Bevan No problem, I'm glad it helped and it will also help future users.

Comment: Good point. Many others will read this thread, and some will use your code.